# How to remove the time from a datetime parameter?

Tags: reporting-services

I have two columns on my SSRS report, one for created date time and one for closed date time.

My report requires a date range parameter that uses these columns through a stored procedure.

My issue is that I do not want the user to have to enter the time stamp of the date time.

I'm not currently sure on what would be the best way to accomplish this.

Comment: can you not just cast the parameter in the SP to a date e.g. `SET @StartDateTimeParam =  CAST(@StartDateTimeParam AS Date)` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
CAST([CDB].[CREATEDDATETIME] AS Date) >= @createdDateStart
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).